# Grok Pattern for Domain name in a list

Tags: regex, grok, logstash-grok

I tried to write an own grok pattern for domain name. But couldn't create it. Someone help me on this.

data format :

```
["test1.example.com", "test2.example.com", "test3.example.com", "new1.example.com", "new2.example.com", "new3.example.com", "dev.example.com"]
```

Sometimes, the above data count may vary means value is dynamic. Like as

```
["test1.example.com", "test2.example.com"]
```

Is there any possibility to create pattern for this?

Comment: What did you try already, and how was it not working for you?

Comment: @eric-renouf I haven't tried it before. Just now , tried to create an own grok pattern for Logstash configuration. But unable to create it. If you have any chance to create, please share that pattern to me.